# Firebase Mobile authentication: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined, js engine: hermes error

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, react-google-recaptcha

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import auth from './firebaseConfig'
import RecaptchaVerifier from 'firebase/auth'

   

// Sent OTP
    const signin = () => {
        if (mynumber === "" || mynumber.length < 10) return;
           window.RecaptchaVerifier  = new RecaptchaVerifier(auth,'recaptcha-container',{});
                const appVerifier = window.RecaptchaVerifier
            signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, mynumber, appVerifier).then((result) => {
              
                });
    }
```

The code is failing with below exception

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined, js engine:
> hermes at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in
> reportException at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in
> handleException ... 7 more stack frames from framework internals

Any help will be appreciatedl̥